# Download / Save file from Web Site / Web Page

Tags: vba, excel

I need to download the PDF files from the link below for the first/top 5 dates and save them on Desktop for instance. I have no clue how to start but also couldn't find something explicit on Google.

Do you think you can help me?

http://cetatenie.just.ro/ordine/articol-11/

Comment: You can start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: OK, the basic idea is clear, is there possible to do this via VBA? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I think that this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2009/02/21/web-scraping-with-vb-s-xml-support.aspx describes exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Internet Explorer, and automate it using an SHDocVw.InternetExplorer object (VBA reference 'Microsoft Internet Controls', ieframe.dll).

You can either (a) create a new Internet Explorer window using `Set x = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` or (b) acquire an existing Internet Explorer window using `Set owins = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows` (`owins` is an array, loop through it until you find one where `Mid(TypeName(owins(i).Document), 1, 12) = "HTMLDocument"`).

Once you have an Internet Explorer `ie`, you can call `ie.Navigate(url)` to go to a website.

To wait for Internet Explorer to finish navigating before you interrogate it, you can run something like:

```
Do While mascot_win.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    DoEvents
Loop
```

To get the URLs for the first five PDFs on that page, you'd need to examine the HTML of the page. There are two ways, depending on how well-formed the HTML is. If the HTML is well-written, then you can navigate the Document Object Model (the tags, like XML) with `ie.Document.all()`. But if the HTML is not well-formed, you may have to resort to reading the HTML from `ie.Document.all(0).innerHTML`.

By the looks of the link you gave, you will be looking for things like:

```
<li>Data de <strong>22.03.2013</strong>, numarul: <a href="/wp-content/uploads/Ordin-149P-din-22.03.2013.pdf">149P</a></li>
```

Once you have isolated each PDF URL (using either the attribute of the `<a>` tag in the DOM model or using lots of `Mid()` calls on the HTML), you can download it using:

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile _
Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
( _
    ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
) As Long

Dim ss As String
Dim ts As String
ss = "http://blah/blah/blah.pdf"
ts = "c:\meh\blah.pdf"
URLDownloadToFile 0, ss, ts, 0, 0
```

Comment: I would say that here is pretty much I need, you did here an amazing work, Ijust need a while to understand better the "isolating" and <a> usage. Thank you very much!

Comment: Laso, forgot to tell you that periodically the page is updated and other files are added periodically. I assume the code shall change a bit...no?

Comment: As long as you are still wanting to download the first five files, and the HTML still follows the same pattern, then you don't need to change the code. The general structure of your code will probably loop through the elements and, after identifying and downloading five files, stop looping. So long as the webpage author is just adding new files to the top of list, using the same pattern as he/she normally does, then your code doesn't need to change.

Comment: @user2185045 The *URLDownloadToFile* function is exactly what I needed, +1, well written reply, thank you very much. Any way to keep the original filename? The URL I'm getting the file from is a PHP script, so I don't know the filename at all but it still has one when I download it directly from my browser.

Comment: @dnLL I don't know which website you're talking about, so I can't say for sure. I imagine there is some quiet redirect magic going on where the PHP script gives your browser some HTML with an automatic redirect to the real file. URLDownloadToFile() is a very convenient convenience function but it may be glossing over this quiet redirect, which is important in your situation. I don't know off the top of my head, but if you post a question with the URL so that I can have a play/test, then I may be able to help.

Comment: It is used with our own local Livelink server but ya, it's just a PHP header redirection. I was able to solve this issue by getting the file name directly from our database with the ID, which did solve my problem for my specific case.